# Difference between Placeholder and parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, terminology

I was watching a course about JDBC and when the Instructor was speaking about `?` (Question Mark) in Prepared Statement, he said:

> Before I execute the Query, I have to fill in the ***placeholders*** or ***parameters***.

he was talking about a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee where salary > ?
```

Now, my main question is:

**what is difference between placeholder and parameter?**

and isn't he wrong? **can `?` be either placeholder or parameter?**

Edit:

I consider these two definition also:

> argument is the value/variable/reference being passed in, parameter is the receiving variable

Comment: He mis-spoke. What he should have said was 'fill in the placeholders with the actual parameters'. That would have made it perfectly clear.

Comment: @user207421 Shouldn't we say 'fill in the placeholders with the arguments'? because parameter was supposed to be a receiving and argument was supposed to be the value being passed in.

Comment: Was there some sort of exam question that made a difference? I would normally consider _placeholder_ and _parameter_ to be synonyms, and the phrase as spoken to be simply explaining different names that you might see for the concept.

Comment: @MehSar In compiler construction you have formal arguments and actual parameters. Same here. The formal argument, or placeholder, is the `?`, and the actual parameter is the value you set it to. But your instructor may have meant the same thing for both.

Comment: @user207421 Thank u very much for explanation. I thought that we have just one type parameter and that's the one that works same actual parameter. I got it.

Comment: @user207421 by the way, are actual parameter and actual argument same thing?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thank u for explanation. not really. I just got confused because in another resources, "?" question mark was called a "parameter placeholder" and then I though they are different and then ... everything got complicated suddenly.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments) answer your question?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes sir. Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, these are just two terms used for the same things. Which is probably why that phrase was used: to introduce both terms and indicate they can be used interchangeably. There is even a third variant where both are combined in a single term: *parameter placeholder*.

As I see it, the `?` is a *placeholder* for a value, but at the same time a *parameter* for the query.